# How to generate CA signed x509 certificate by M2Crypto

Tags: m2crypto, csr, x509

I have a CSR file and CA keys

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [x509 unit tests](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/tests/test_x509.py) and the [PKI demo](http://svn.osafoundation.org/m2crypto/trunk/contrib/SimpleX509create.py) in contribs. The latter might need tweaks since it has not been maintained.

Comment: Rotten link? Here's another: http://svn.tribler.org/m2crypto/trunk/contrib/SimpleX509create.py

Comment: Links are rotten.